# PHP cookie is not url safe

Tags: php, url, cookies

I am using PHP to create cookie using

```
setcookie("key", "value@value");
```

but if we check the cookie in browser resources it shows `value%40value`.
I need it to be `value@value`

When I created cookie using Java, I see proper value `value@value`.

I already tried `urldecode` and `urlencode` functions. None of them worked.

Comment: `urldecode("value%40value")` works as expected for me...

Comment: the $var="value@value" is actually coming from the user as a post parameter. On the server side it shows correctly. when I am setting cookie, i use setcookie("key",$var). but after cookie is created it shows "key",value%40value. How can I avoid this? I have already tried urldecode($var). It gives the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using [setrawcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setrawcookie.php). Take a look at what the [docs](https://www.php.net/setcookie) have to say on the subject:

> Note that the value portion of the cookie will automatically be
> urlencoded when you send the cookie, and when it is received, it is
> automatically decoded and assigned to a variable by the same name as
> the cookie name. If you don't want this, you can use
> [setrawcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setrawcookie.php)
> instead if you are using PHP 5.